# How Can I bypass Zoho Creator Records Run limit?

Tags: function, loops, range, record, zoho

I have an issue with the limits of record I can run in Zoho Creator in my script, so I have been using Ranges - (ie. run from record 1 to let's say 100, 101 to 200, 201 to 300, 301...); but now I have very many records(40000). Is there a way I can write two or more functions that can run through the records without I defining the ranges time after time?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get the number of records available first.
Based on that count, batch it.

Example: for 4102 records => [(4102 / 100) + ((4102 % 100) > 0 ? 1 : 0)]
and download it with sleep time between each request, to prevent blocking of the requests.